# Numpy: efficiently expand a matrix from submatrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

Given a square array D of dimension(4x4):

```
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
```

how can you, for each sub-matrix d of size (2x2) create another set of matrices D*, such that

```
D* = [..., 
         [[ 1,  2,  1,  2],
          [ 3,  4,  3,  4],
          [ 1,  2,  1,  2],
          [ 3,  4,  3,  4]]
     ]
```

I then wish to build another square array out of D*, D**, such that:

```
D** =    [[ 1,  2,  1,  2,  5,  6,  5,  6],
          [ 3,  4,  3,  4,  7,  8,  7,  8],
          [ 1,  2,  1,  2,  5,  6,  5,  6],
          [ 3,  4,  3,  4,  7,  8,  7,  8],
          [ 9,  10,  9, 10, 13, 14, 13, 14],
          [ 11, 12, 11, 12, 15, 16, 15, 16],
          [ 9,  10,  9, 10, 13, 14, 13, 14],
          [ 11, 12, 11, 12, 15, 16, 15, 16]]]
```

My actual starting matrix D's dimension is 184x184, so I found that for-loops were too slow to achieve this. Is this too computationally intensive for numpy? Or is there a way to achieve this elegantly an efficiently?

Here is an example of the foor-loop pseudo-code:

```
segments = [(0,0), (2,2), (0,2), (2, 0)]
for seg in segments:
    actual_seg = D[seg[0]:seg[0]+2, seg[1]:seg[1]+2]
    D*.append(numpy.kron(numpy.ones((2, 2), dtype=int), actual_seg))
```

Comment: This simple example is not enough to understand the mathematical functions that brings D to D* and D**. Can you formalize better how you create D* and D**? Maybe including your 4-for loops code

Comment: So, D* means "tile each *non-overlapping* sub matrix 2 by 2 and make a list", and D** means "tile all these matrices in D* into one big matrix"? Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Given `D` and looking to expand each such `(2x2)` submatrix, one approach using a combination of [`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) would be -

```
m,n = D.shape
out = np.repeat(np.tile(D.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2),2),2,axis=0).reshape(2*m,2*n)
```

Sample run -

```
In [116]: D
Out[116]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])

In [117]: m,n = D.shape

In [118]: np.repeat(np.tile(D.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2),2),2,axis=0).reshape(2*m,2*n)
Out[118]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  1,  2,  5,  6,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  3,  4,  7,  8,  7,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  1,  2,  5,  6,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  3,  4,  7,  8,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10,  9, 10, 13, 14, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 11, 12, 15, 16, 15, 16],
       [ 9, 10,  9, 10, 13, 14, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 11, 12, 15, 16, 15, 16]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

def fn(m_):
        rows, cols = m_.shape
        assert rows%2==0 and cols%2==0
        return np.reshape(
            np.transpose(
                np.tile(
                    np.transpose(
                        np.reshape(
                            m_,(rows//2,2, cols//2,2)
                        ),(0,2,1,3)),(2,2)), (0,2,1,3)
            ),
            (rows*2,cols*2)
        )

m = np.array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
    [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
    [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
    [11, 12, 15, 16]])

print(fn(m))
```

output:

```
[[ 1  2  1  2  5  6  5  6]
 [ 3  4  3  4  7  8  7  8]
 [ 1  2  1  2  5  6  5  6]
 [ 3  4  3  4  7  8  7  8]
 [ 9 10  9 10 13 14 13 14]
 [11 12 11 12 15 16 15 16]
 [ 9 10  9 10 13 14 13 14]
 [11 12 11 12 15 16 15 16]]
```